# How to Solve an ODE involving three Functions of the Coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation which is

$-i\alpha_1 v_1(x^1,x^2,R) - i \alpha_2v_2(x^1,x^2,R)+\frac{d v_3}{d x^3}=0.$

So to be clear, the $v_i$'s are separate quantities as they are different components of a velocity vector which depend on the three coordinates, where the third coordinate takes a constant value $R$.  How exactly would one solve this?

Comment: When you say that the $3^{rd}$ coordinate is fixed, do you mean that $x_3 = R$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct ie. it always takes a constant value in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As $x^3 = R$, we have $v_3 = 0$, and so $\frac{dv_3}{dx^3} = 0$. Thus, the equation simplifies to $$\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2 = 0$$
or
$$\alpha_1\frac{dx^1}{dt}+\alpha_2\frac{dx^2}{dt} = 0$$
Integrating, we get - 
$$\alpha_1x^1+\alpha_2x^2 = C$$
where $C$ is a constant depending on the initial conditions of the differential equation.

Comment: Hi, I should have clarified this, although they are components of a velocity vector, they are actually the Fourier transformed components which I am solving for, so not sure if this argument holds.

Comment: So I think I need to solve for the equation algebraically as it were, without using the fact that they are components of a velocity, just that they are functions of the space coordinates.